# Как установить pip для Python 3.7

Tags: pandas, pip, sqlalchemy, python-3.7

У меня Python 3.7., нужен pip для установки Pandas. Не могу разобраться, нужна пошаговая инструкция. ОС Windows 10 х64. Использую интерпретатор PyCharm. Где скачать и как установить pip. В pip установить pandas и sqlalchemy?

Comment: Никак не надо, в 3.х уже из коробки есть.

Comment: я ввожу   import pandas as pd, выдает ошибку:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Comment: И как отсюда следует, что нет pip? А что pandas не установлен, к вопросу не относится.

Comment: Я pip в настройках не нашел, но если он установлен, как тогда в pip установить pandas и sqlalchemy, последнее предложение в вопросе?

Comment: В каких настройках? А как установить модуль через пип написано на каждом сайте про питон.

Comment: В PyCharm File | Settings | Project: untitled7 | Project Interpreter - пустые поля, не активна кнопка "+" чтобы добавить Install Pandas on Pycharm

Comment: Я не пойму - вопрос про pip или pycharm? Какие сложности забить в гугл "pip установить pandas" и получить ответ через секунду?

Comment: _"интерпретатор PyCharm"_, — звучит странно, ведь это `IDE`. Попробуйте просто ввести в консоли: `pip install pandas`.

Comment: Если project interpreter вообще не указан в настройках, то его нужно указать. Тогда и пакеты можно будет устанавливать.

Answer (score 0):

Если используете PyCharm тогда так:

- Создаете новый проект
- Переходим в File - Settings - Project Interpreter
- В открывшимся окне в верху есть срока поиска, там ищем нужный пакет
- Жмем кнопку Install package

Или же в PyCharm внизу слева есть кнопка Terminal, открываем его, и в нем уже пишем `pip install pandas`

Answer (score 0):

Нужно зайти на официальный сайт python и заново скачать Python 3.7 т.к. pip идет python из коробки. Потом можно просто открыть любой эмулятор терминала, будь-то cmd, windows Terminal или ConEmu и далее уже использовать команды `pip install *`

Comment: Не понятна логика. Если Python 3.7 уже установлен, и pip идет c python из коробки, то не понятно зачем заново скачивать.

Comment: ну какой вопрос, такой ответ